# Cstring message contains the same character \n and it does not extract newline

Tags: visual-c++

strPrompt is my input string that can be texts, numbers or symbols and has 2 lines: 
- pause("this\n try is\n a test")
- pause("this try is the second try ")
I expect that \n  make new  line in CString message, but it doesn't happen and I see exactly the same text contains \n.
How can I extract newline to the message?

```
FTry Pause::ExecuteMyFunction() const
{
FTry try;
std::string strPrompt;

if( arg > 1)
    return ArgError( "The number of arguments are too much!");

if( arg == 1 && !arg( PROMPT, strPrompt))
    return ArgError( "Invalid message");


CString message = ( arg == 0 ? "Run the script?" :  strPrompt.c_str() );


return try;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried \r\n, but I got the same result . I see \r\n in the printed message.

Comment: Show the code in which you create the CStrings. The backslashes must be escaped somehow for this to happen.

Comment: @eran : THis is the way I create the CString.

Comment: `CString::CString(const CString& stringSrc)
{
 if (stringSrc.GetData()->nRefs >= 0 && stringSrc.GetData() != _afxDataNil) {
  m_pchData = stringSrc.m_pchData;
  GetData()->nRefs++;
 }
 else {
  Init();
  *this = stringSrc.m_pchData;
 }
}`

Comment: The CString constructor is not the issue. If the `arg` function assigns `PROMPT` into strPrompt, then how does PROMPT gets its content? I.e., is it a string literal with hardcoded `\n`s, or does it get its content from the console, command line or some text file? To make this simpler, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The irrelevant code in your question is a distraction for both of us.

Answer (score 0):

Windows require line ends to be the combination of `\r\n`, and not just `\n`. Add the `\r` and your lines will break properly.

(You mention you see the `\n` in the printed string. I'm assuming you see it as a space or weird char, and not as a backslash followed by an n. If the latter is the case, your strings contain an extra backslash)